# Navbar on top of background image bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, styles

I am trying to have my navbar be on top of my background imagein bootstrap 4.0. I can do this via negative margin top on the background image but that is not easy to work with if i make changes to my site.

HTML:

```
<div class="masthead">
    <nav>
        <img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/testIO-logo-rgb-2.png" class="site-logo" />
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid hero"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(https://s17736.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/asoggetti-318284-unsplash-1024x684.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

nav {
  background: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: auto,center;
}

.site-logo {
  height: 64px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6fsL4bc/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `display:relative;` to parent div and `display:absolute;` and `top:0;` to child(nav).
>
> Whenever you need the logo(which is common use case) to put on the top without using the negative values then use, positions for `parent` and `child`, if there are no parent then the `body` will be considered as parent and it will positioned absolute to body.

You don't have to use negative value since the absolute will fit-in the image as expected for all instances.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/410k9pq8/2/) to playaround.

```css
.hero {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(https://s17736.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/asoggetti-318284-unsplash-1024x684.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.masthead {
  display: relative;
}

nav {
  background: transparent;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: auto, center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.site-logo {
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <nav>
    <img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/testIO-logo-rgb-2.png" class="site-logo" />
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid hero"> </div>
```